# Prettier formatter not working for .sol files, but works with .js, .css, etc

Tags: solidity, prettier

At the bottom of VS Code the prettier icon is a cross out icon when in a .sol file, but when I'm in other file types it's a checkmark.

[Here's the error message I receive when I try to format the solidity file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhWFE.png)

[The icon I'm referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Jum.png)

I've read through some of the other post on similar problems and can't seem to get it to work by following those suggestions. I also got a message when trying to format saying prettier doesn't work with solidity, but I've used it for .sol files before.

Comment: Out of box not possible, it only accepts these formats -- JavaScript, TypeScript, HTML, CSS, JSON, YAML, and Markdown files. It doesn't directly support Solidity (.sol)